# virtualenv could not install on my machine due to permission denied

Tags: django, virtualenv

```
creating c:\program files\python38\Lib\site-packages\distlib
error: could not create 'c:\program files\python38\Lib\site-packages\distlib': Access is denied
----------------------------------------
```

**How do I fix this?
I tried to install virtualenv and django but got the error above**

Comment: You should run the installation as administrator

Comment: Can you show the command you ran and where you ran it? e.g. (bash, cmd , etc?)

Comment: I used powershell to pip install virtualenv

Comment: I used admin account and it worked but how do I make use of the installation?

Comment: Can you try running powershell as an administrator, separately?